# clientX/clientY and moving out of range works intermittently

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script that triggers when the user moves the mouse out of the main window. I got it working intermittently with clientX/clientY. Why is it not triggered consiquently?

```
onmousemove = function (e) {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;

  if (e.clientX == 1 || e.clientX == w - 1) {
    console.log("Modal window pop-up!");
  } else if (e.clientY == 1 || e.clientY == h - 1) {
    console.log("Modal window pop-up!");
  }
};
```

Comment: Outside of the browser window?

Comment: Check when the mouse position is less/more than the limits, it's rare that the position would hit exactly on the limits.

Comment: Outside the 'enviroment', not browser window completely.

Comment: @Teemu I tried that but I want it to be exactly at 0 or "max width" or "max height" of the enviroment window. Why is it like that?

Comment: It's not possible, when you move the mouse, the mousemove event doesn't fire fast enough to detect the position pixel by pixel.

Comment: @teemu Ok, I understand thank you for a quick reply! :) How do I make this solved now?

Comment: Like I said in the comment, check if the position has gone out of the limits. Depending on what you really want to do in that case, you might have some options to make the detection a bit more accurate. But if you only want to show a pop-up or log to the console, I wouldn't bother to make things more complex.

Comment: @teemu, Like this you mean? 

`if (e.clientX <= 5 || e.clientX >= w * 0.95) {
    console.log("Modal window pop-up!");
  } else if (e.clientY <= 5 || e.clientY >= h * 0.95) {
    console.log("Modal window pop-up!");
  }`

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @teemu, I tried this before and its not accurate enough and it kind destroys the pixel perfect design. I've been playing around with "onmouseout" a bit and it seems to work better but I only get it to work on EVERY element so it triggers all over the page when I only want it to be the whole window. Any ideas on this? `let html = document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0];
html.onmouseout = function () {
  console.log("Modal pop-up!");
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the wrong path. First I tried "onmouseout" and didn't get the desired outcome wich led me to try the clientX/clientY way. That also missed the desired effect. Eventually I tried with "onmouseleave" and it became perfect. Here is my solution:

```
let html = document.getElementById("dimScreen");
html.onmouseleave = function () {
  console.log("Modal pop-up!");
};
```